# QuestionRow-level security in Entity Framework 4.0/4.1

Tags: entity-framework, entity

1. Is it possible to implement row level security or Global filters functionality in Entity Framework like session.filters in nHibernate ORM?  Do we have some open source code or links for the same? If yes Please share.
2. Apart from that if we implement such a filter manually how can we change the filter dynamically for each user? please share some code.
3. Can we use manually filters using EntityObjects approach or POCO approach or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - there are no global filters. If you want them you must wrap context into some another layer and create your own solution for global filters. The problem here is that even if you create "a filter" (= custom extension method) you must manually apply it to the query and even after that it is applied only to the main query but it is not applied to eager or lazy loaded relations.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav for your reply, just wondering how can I pre-filter the context objects dynamically for each user also does I manually redefine the filters for navigation properties too?

Comment: You do not pre-filter objects. You simply add special fitler condition to each your query or you will wrap the context and its set to some another layer and it will always return `IQueryalbe` with filter already applied. In case of navigations there is no way at all. If you want to filter navigation properties you must do it completely manually and you cannot use neither eager loading or lazy loading - you must use projection to custom classes.

Comment: hmm got you but if lazy/eager loading is not working, there is no use to create wrapper and its too complex to filter the navigation properties manually, need to think about some another approach. Thanks for the reply Ladislav

Comment: You can filter navigation properties only with explicit loading where you let EF create basis of the query from navigation property and add some filter.

Comment: can we not return ObjectQuery<T> instead of IQueryable  which have functions like include etc